# tcolorbox in tabular environment misaligned

Tags: tables, macros, moderncv, tcolorbox

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,english]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[scale=0.75,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=ydnt,dashed=false,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2cm}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{222, 216, 243}
\tcbset{
    frame code={}
    bottom title,
    box align=base,
    colback=mycolor,
    colframe=black,
    width=\maincolumnwidth,
    boxsep=4pt,
    arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
}




\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
    \begin{tabular}{p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}}%
        \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} & {#3}%
    \end{tabular}%
    \par\addvspace{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
    \cvitem[#1]{
        #2
    }{% 
            \begin{tcolorbox}[tcbox raise base]         
        {\bfseries#3\newline}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{{\slshape#4, }}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{#6\newline}%
            \end{tcolorbox}
        .\strut%
        \ifx&#7&%
        \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
\begin{document}
\cventry{arg2}{arg3}{arg4}{arg5}{arg6}{arg7}
\end{document}
```

See the result here:
[image]

What I would like to achieve is to have `arg2` top aligned (in line with `arg3`). It seems that `p{\hintscolumnwidth}` in `\cvitem` does not work properly. Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe what you really need is the `colortbl` package? It lets you lay out tables as usually be also paint individual cells, columns, or rows with background colour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alignment is difficult, unless doing a trick: Use another `tcolorbox` for the left column (where `arg2`) appears, establishing an `equal height group` for each `cventry` by stepping the counter `equalheightgroup`.

I suggest to use three styles as well: `moderncvcommon`, `moderncvbox` and `itembox`, where `moderncvcommon` is used by both `moderncvbox` and `itembox`. This allows to change the specifications of alignment etc for both boxes.

Some sidenotes: `\newline` does not have an argument, nor does `\else`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,english]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[scale=0.75,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=ydnt,dashed=false,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2cm}

\newcounter{equalheightgroup}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{222, 216, 243}


\tcbset{%
  moderncvcommon/.style={ 
    enhanced,
    frame hidden,
    sharp corners,
    box align=top,
    boxsep=4pt,
    nobeforeafter,
    equal height group=cvitem\number\value{equalheightgroup}
  },
  moderncvbox/.style={ 
    moderncvcommon,
    colback=mycolor,
    width=\maincolumnwidth,
  },
  itembox/.style={%
    moderncvcommon,
    colback=white,
    width=\hintscolumnwidth+\tabcolsep+\separatorcolumnwidth},
}




\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
    \begin{tabular}{p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}}%
        \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} & {#3}%
    \end{tabular}%
    \par\addvspace{#1}}

  \renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
    \stepcounter{equalheightgroup}% 
    \cvitem[#1]{%
      \begin{tcolorbox}[itembox]
        #2%
      \end{tcolorbox}
    }{% 
      \begin{tcolorbox}[moderncvbox]
        \textbf{#3}\newline%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{{\slshape#4, }}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{#6\newline}%
      \end{tcolorbox}
      .\strut%
      \ifx&#7&%
      \else
      \newline
      \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi
}

\firstname{foo}
\lastname{bar}
\begin{document}
\cventry{arg2}{arg3}{arg4}{arg5}{arg6}{arg7}
\end{document}
```

[image]